# displaying CollectionViewController in Playground

Tags: xcode, swift-playground, collectionview

I am simply trying to display a CollectionView in playground to quickly try out ideas.  Yet this has been a hour+ affair.  I'm getting the error:

> 2017-03-17 17:28:37.862 uikitTest[88414:10270872] *** Assertion failure in -[UICollectionView _dequeueReusableViewOfKind:withIdentifier:forIndexPath:viewCategory:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3600.6.21/UICollectionView.m:4971
>   2017-03-17 17:28:37.866 uikitTest[88414:10270872] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'could not dequeue a view of kind: UICollectionElementKindCell with identifier test1 - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'
>   *** First throw call stack:

I tried setting a view to the PlaygroundPage, and also creating a UIWindow.  It isn't clear to me how to work with ViewControllers in Playground, and even whether this is the root problem and if its connected to the `could not dequeue` exception.

My Playground is as follows:

```
 import UIKit
import XCPlayground
import PlaygroundSupport


class CVCCell: UICollectionViewCell {

   let label = UILabel()

   override init(frame: CGRect) {
      super.init(frame: .zero)
   }

   required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
      fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
   }

   override func layoutSubviews() {
      label.frame = bounds
   }
}

class CVC: UICollectionViewController {

   var datasource = ["1","2","3"]

   override func viewDidLoad() {
      view.backgroundColor = .red


      print(collectionView)
      collectionView?.register(CVCCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "test1")
   }

   override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
      return datasource.count
   }

   override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

      let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "test1", for: indexPath) as! CVCCell
      cell.label.text = datasource[indexPath.row]
      return cell
   }

}


let containerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0,
                                 y: 0.0,
                                 width: 375.0,
                                 height: 667.0))

containerView.backgroundColor = .green

let fl = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
let cvc = CVC(collectionViewLayout: fl)



let w = UIWindow(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 320, height: 480))
w.rootViewController = cvc


print(cvc.view)

containerView.addSubview(cvc.view)
//PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = containerView
```

Comment: https://github.com/tnantoka/swift-playground/blob/master/CollectionView/CollectionView/CollectionViewController.swift

Comment: that isn't helpful

Comment: got any solution?

Comment: @SabhaySardana something to do with accessing the view to trigger viewDidLoad so it ran registering cell code or something... anyway heres working code 
https://gist.github.com/AlexanderBollbach/d529750804469641857b7abb36a6875c